# lm() breaks when using poly() with predictors set up as factors

Tags: r, regression, lm, poly

I'm trying to model the relationship between a categorical predictor variable and a continuous outcome variable. I use `lm()` to this end. Since it's a categorical variable, the proper practice is to convert it to a factor variable type. However, when using `poly()` for the predictor's regression term **and** when setting up the predictor variable as a factor it causes `lm()` to break. On the other hand, if I run `lm()` without using `poly()` (but do keep the predictor as factor) *or* keep `poly()` but not convert the predictor to a factor (let it be numeric) -- then `lm()` doesn't break. I don't understand why it breaks and I don't understand if I can trust the results when it doesn't break.

### Data

Data about 50 basketball players. One column (`PosCode`) is about player's position in the game, and the other (`Height`) is player's height.

```r
data <-
structure(list(Player = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50), PosCode = c(3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 
1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 5, 5, 2, 1, 2, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 
2), Height = c(176.1, 179.1, 183.1, 169.7, 177.3, 179, 176.4, 
174.9, 180.2, 176.5, 178.6, 167.9, 183.4, 166.2, 189.5, 171.9, 
188.5, 172.6, 167.7, 172.6, 186.9, 163.8, 179.3, 165.4, 182.2, 
166.1, 176.8, 171.9, 173.8, 163, 172.5, 184.9, 170.4, 170.6, 
166.8, 172.6, 184.3, 163.3, 182.4, 165.8, 173.4, 182.1, 172.9, 
184.9, 173.2, 185.8, 161.4, 186, 178.4, 170.7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


> data
## # A tibble: 50 x 3
##    Player PosCode Height
##    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
##  1      1       3   176.
##  2      2       3   179.
##  3      3       4   183.
##  4      4       1   170.
##  5      5       4   177.
##  6      6       1   179 
##  7      7       3   176.
##  8      8       1   175.
##  9      9       2   180.
## 10     10       2   176.
## # ... with 40 more rows
```

### Modeling the data

I want to know whether I can predict players height from their position in the game. Since position is categorical (there are 5 possible positions), this variable should be of a factor type, with 5 levels.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr) 

data %<>% mutate_at(vars(PosCode), ~ as.factor(.)) ## convert PosCode from dbl to fct
```

#### Modeling by using `lm()` *without* `poly()`

```r
lm(Height ~ PosCode, data = data)

## Call:
## lm(formula = Height ~ PosCode, data = data)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)     PosCode2     PosCode3     PosCode4     PosCode5  
##    173.6714       4.9397       0.4429       0.1824       4.1857
```

#### Modeling by using `lm()` *with* `poly()`

```r
lm(Height ~ poly(PosCode ,1), data = data)

## Error in qr.default(X) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
## In addition: Warning messages:
## 1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
## 2: In Ops.factor(x, xbar) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

#### If the predictor isn't a factor, there's no problem regardless of `poly()`

```r
## convert PosCode from fct back to dbl
data %<>% mutate_at(vars(PosCode), ~ as.double(.)) 

## lm() without poly()
lm(Height ~ PosCode, data = data)

Call:
lm(formula = Height ~ PosCode, data = data)

## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)      PosCode  
##   174.3848       0.3112 


## lm() with poly() 
lm(Height ~ poly(PosCode ,1), data = data)

## Call:
## lm(formula = Height ~ poly(PosCode, 1), data = data)

## Coefficients:
##      (Intercept)  poly(PosCode, 1)  
##          175.256             3.173
```

But clearly, treating `PosCode` as `dbl` rather than `fct` changes the model in a way that is wrong.

### Bottom line

I don't understand why including `poly()` in `lm()` breaks it when the predictor is set up as a factor variable.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to explain what you're trying to achieve. It's not clear to be what e.g. "the square of a players position" would mean if it could be calculated

Comment: IMHO, the problem has nothing to do with `lm()`. A categorical predictor (a factor in R) has to be recoded into, for example, dummy variables and the number of (dummy) variables is one less than the number of categories. This is why you get four coefficients in the first model. And then having, say, a quadratic effect for such a (binary dummy) predictor doesn't make sense, `poly()` makes only sense for continuous predictors.

Comment: @Miff, what I'm trying to achieve is how to predict player's height from position. If I know that a player "Danny" plays in the position coded as 3, what is the most likely height for this player? What squaring the  player's position has to do with this? Maybe I'm misusing `poly()` then?

Comment: What was your reason for using `poly()`? In the end, it's not of much use unless you set `degree` to a value > 1.

Comment: @hplieninger, I thought that using `poly()` with `degree = 1` is interchangeable to not using `poly()` at all. So mindlessly I kept it from using a different model. Then it broke. This surprised me because `degree` of 1 shouldn't be a problem. But I guess `poly()` can't accept non-numeric variables whatsoever?

Comment: Okay, so you definitely should remove `poly()`. To reiterate, this behavior of `poly()` is expected, sensible and documented ("a numeric vector ..."), and other functions or statistical software should error as well.

Comment: I see, thanks. Please make this an answer so I could choose it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `help("poly")`:

> `x` a **numeric** vector at which to evaluate the polynomial.

Thus, you cannot use factors inside `poly()`. This is expected, because categorical variables (i.e., factors) have to be recoded, for example, into dummy variables. And it does neither make sense to have, say, a quadratic effect for the categorical variable as a whole nor for the coded (dummy) variables. (It does not make sense from a substantive perspective, but squaring a dummy variable that has only 0s and 1s does also not make much sense from a perspective blind to statistics.)

You can see that `lm()` recodes your factor because you get four coefficents (one less than the number of categories) for the variable `PosCode` in your first model.

In the end, `poly()` is not of much use unless you set its argument `degree` to a value > 1